# Cannot bring up network on hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm following [this documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#bring-up-the-network) to build my first network but after following the same steps as the documentation, I received an error that I could not find a solution to...

This is the error:

```
 “Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Post "http://unix.sock/containers/create?name=dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0": dial unix /host/var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode instantiation on peer0.org2 on channel 'mychannel' failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!”
```

These are solutions I've tried:

1. Turning it off and back on.
2. Running it in a different language.
3. Pruning the network.
4. Removing any conflicting images.

I tried changing the variables in the docker-compose.yaml file but nothing happened. I am not experienced in this topic and this is my first time interacting with hyperledger fabric. Also, why do these commands not run in powershell but only work in git bash?

I am running these commands on Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use hyperledger fabric 1.4 which is now out of support. The instructions for windows were updated in the latest documentation so you might want to start looking at
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html#windows
for the recommended pre-requisites.

Then you can go on to install the samples and test environment described https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

All shells have their own language syntax for shell scripts, so powershell has it's own language syntax and so won't understand scripts written for a bash shell. Bash shell is the predominant shell for linux (and is also popular on Macs) so bash was the environment chosen for these scripts to run in. Now that Windows has the Windows Subsystem for Linux Version 2 (WSL2), Windows now provides an excellent environment linux development.